# ImportError: cannot import name 'Markup' from 'flask'

Tags: python, flask

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAty7.png)

This specific error : ImportError: cannot import name 'Markup' from 'flask'
expected the flask app to start running.

I have tried the following :

1.

```
from markupsafe import Markup
```

2. 

Re-installed flask and upgraded using `pip install --upgrade flask`

```
import os
from markupsafe import Markup
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_dropzone import Dropzone


basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.update(
    UPLOADED_PATH = os.path.join(basedir, 'uploads'),
    DROPZONE_MAX_FILE_SIZE = 1024,
    DROPZONE_TIMEOUT = 5*60*1000
)

dropzone = Dropzone(app) 

@app.route('/', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])

def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files.get('file')
        f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOADED_PATH'], f.filename))
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

But the error still persists.

Comment: Please avoid [posting images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 3):

Recent versions of Flask appear to have sunset flask.Markup.  However, the following should work:

- uninstall the current version of Flask
- reinstall an older version, e.g. *pip install flask==2.3.1*
- remove this line

> from markupsafe import Markup

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after upgrading flask to 3.0.2.

After checking the error log noticed that the error was raised by Flask-WTF.

By Upgrading Flask-WTF to 1.2.1 (current latest version) all was fixed.