# ImportError: cannot import name Markup from flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, pycharm

**I'd tried this**;

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for
    from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap5
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
    from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
    from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
    from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, URL
    from flask_ckeditor import CKEditor, CKEditorField
```

**Then i came across this**
**Output**;

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/mustafa/Desktop/Backend/REST-API/some_project/main.py", line 7, in <module>
        from flask_ckeditor import CKEditor, CKEditorField
      File "/home/mustafa/Desktop/Backend/REST-API/some_project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-    packages/flask_ckeditor/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
        from flask import current_app, Markup, Blueprint, url_for, request, jsonify,     render_template_string
    ImportError: cannot import name 'Markup' from 'flask' (/home/mustafa/Desktop/Backend/REST-    API/some_project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/__init__.py)
```

requirements.txt;

```
    Bootstrap_Flask==2.3.0
    Flask==3.0.0
    Flask_CKEditor==0.4.6
    flask_sqlalchemy==3.1.1
    Flask_WTF==1.2.1
    WTForms==3.0.1
```

[This is not same issue for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77249838/importerror-cannot-import-name-markup-from-flask)

I had looked same question tag which similar my question title but i wasn't find any solution for my case. Please Help.

Comment: A fix has been released, so you have to use flask-ckeditor version 0.5.0 because flask-3.0.0 is no longer using Markup from markupsafe library

Answer (score 1):

found this solution for the issues:

```
pip install markupsafe
```

code

```
from markupsafe import Markup  # Import Markup from markupsafe

 def load(css_url=None, js_url=None, serve_local=False):
        # ... rest of the load method ...
        return Markup('''<link rel="stylesheet" href="%s" type="text/css">\n
            <script src="%s"></script>''' % (css_url, js_url))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Flask is using Jinja2 for quite some time, they removed the re-export of Markup with the 3.0.0 release, see [GitHub](https://github.com/pallets/flask/pull/5223).

I suggest you either use a prior 2.3.x version of flask, where this import is still supported, or do not use flask_ckeditor.

Comment: Thanks sir, I've fixed it by manually importing the Markup from another module instead of the flask.